# в чём разница установить систему организации и установить порядок организации?

Tags: словосочетания, смысл

организация рассматривается в смысле слаженность чего - либо или кого - либо

Comment: Немного прилежания и..., и вопрос можно будет понять.

Comment: конкретнее, пожайлуста, чего вы не поняли? Кому - то понятно, а кому - то ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, **что сочетаемость должна быть такой**: создать, разработать систему или установить, учредить порядок.

Задачи разной сложности: система – это сложная структура, а порядок может быть  последовательностью  каких-либо действий.

**Пример:** Положение устанавливает **порядок организации** и проведения проверок юридических лиц и индивидуальных предпринимателей.

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ, но у меня в кое - каком приложение буквально написано "установить систему организации". Ваш ответ навёл меня на решение проблемы, а именно: установить систему - это не только выполнять определённый порядок действий, но и размышлять к чему это приведёт, а порядок - это требуется выполнение определённых действий без всякого размышления.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, порядок организации как слаженности - это установленное устроителями организации взаимодействие в деталях (последовательное и параллельное) отдельных ее частей и правила для ее участников. Например, выборы или спортивные соревнования, или гуманитарная помощь. А система организации - то же в другом уменьшенном масштабе, без деталей.

Comment: как понять - в другом уменьшенном смысле. Мне не очень понятно ...

Comment: Не в уменьшенном смысле, а в другом масштабе. Как если смотреть на город с большой высоты или с малой. "Система" - с большой. С малой высоты можно увидеть только часть, но в деталях.